# Error sending command: 'int' object is not callable in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am facing an issue where whenever i run this command, I get Error sending command: 'int' object is not callable as an error. My code is

```
    @commands.slash_command(name='links',
                            description='Views the links to our site',)
    async def links(self, inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
        try:
            embed = disnake.Embed(title="Website", color=0x00FFFF())
            embed.add_field (name='Website', value='https://www.atmospheresupport.online')
            embed.add_field (name='Docs', value='https://docs.atmospheresupport.online/atmosphere/')
            embed.add_field (name='Status', value='https://atmosphere.pagefate.com')
            embed.set_footer(text=f'Requested by {inter.author}', icon_url=inter.author.avatar.url)
            await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error sending message: {e}')
            await inter.send(embed=errors.create_error_embed(f"Error sending command: {e} it"))
```

it had a different error before i reformatted the code, now this is what im getting.

Comment: Problem is this: `disnake.Embed(..., color=0x00FFFF())` - `0x00FFFF` is parsed as an integer. Treating an integer like a function/callable obviously doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'd like to see the complete traceback. Please add it to the question. As a guess, I think `color=0x00FFFF()` is the root-cause here.

Comment: Yes, it was the color, but I cant find a way to set the embed color as a custom HEX.

Comment: I believe you just pass the hex as a string. `color="00FFFF"`

Comment: use a discord.py embed generator.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom hex color just paste in the color code:

```py
embed = disnake.Embed(title="Website", color=0x00FFFF)
```